# NN on tensorflow doesn't train

Tags: tensorflow

I try to train a simple tensorflow-network on a simple model, but from some reason, it doesn't learn anything. Do I make any mistake?

```py
X, Y = read_data(file_name)

# CONSTRUCT GRAPH
x_t = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, X.shape[1]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_t = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.float32)

hidden_1 = tf.layers.dense(x_t, 50, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
hidden_2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden_1, 50, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
output = tf.layers.dense(hidden_2, 1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)

# DEFINE LOSS AND OPTIMIZER
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output - y_t))
GD_optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_step = GD_optimizer.minimize(loss)

# BATCH SIZE
BATCH_SIZE = 20

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(15000):
        rand_indices = np.random.choice(X.shape[0], size=BATCH_SIZE)

        x_batch = X[rand_indices,:]
        y_batch = Y[rand_indices]

        _, temp_loss = sess.run([train_step, loss], feed_dict={x_t: x_batch, y_t: y_batch})
        print(temp_loss)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't learn anything"? Maybe, the issue with data you provide to a model, so it's hard to help you without you providing sample of data and what you expect of a model.

Comment: The input vector (elements of X) is a 100-dimensional array of float numbers. The outputs are just numbers of 0 or 1. By "doesn't learn anything" I mean, that the loss doesn't fall during the training. I expect that the loss decreases

Comment: You probably need to normalize your input data. Your model is fine.

Comment: Try to provide your model with synthetic data that has strong correlation, then you'll see whether the problem is with your data or with a model.

Comment: The normalization of the data didn't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your dataset description, the target value column `Y` is a float (real valued number) that can be in any range and not necessarily within the [0,1] interval.

On the otherhand, because you use a `sigmoid` activation for the last layer of your model. The prediction values will be always in `[0, 1]` range.

I would suggest not using `sigmoid` activation in the last layer. Unless if your Y value were also in the [0,1] range.

so, modify your code such that it becomes

```
output = tf.layers.dense(hidden_2, 1, activation=None)
```

Comment: The target values are stored in the floating number array but are always values of exactly 0.0 or 1.0.  But I tried to remove the sigmoid activation and the problem still exists, the loss doesn't decrease

Comment: are you doing classification or regression ? If the output values are exactly 0 or 1.0 then it sounds like a binary classification problem and in such a case I would recommend using binary_cross_entropy (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/binary_crossentropy)  as loss instead of mean squared error.